# Ruby on Rails 4 in a LAMP stack server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, lamp

This is the main and most important question:
**What is the best and less complicated way to run Rails 4 apps in Linux/Apache servers?**

Secondary:
Why are we as Rails Developers so tightly related to Heroku? Why there hasn't been a mainstream heavyweight competitor? or who are they? and who provides such an easy way to deploy Rails apps?

Comment: This is a very large question to answer and it's mostly subjective. You should narrow down your request. Moreover, the P in LAMP stays for "PHP", and Rails is built on top of Ruby.

Comment: Puppet, Chef, and Vagrant are provisioning mechanisms. There are several mainstream competitors to Heroku--the reason a lot of people use Heroku is because they have a lot of mindshare.

Comment: Thanks Simone Carletti. I do understand that LAMP is Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP. But I have heard that it is possible to run Rails Apps on top of LAMP. I could be wrong, but that's why I want to know.

Comment: Dave Newton, thanks for your answer. Can you please explain or point out an straightforward explanation about what exactly do those provisioning mechanisms? (Puppet, Chef, Vagrant)? 
In other scope, which are those Heroku Competitors, why most of the time Heroku is the standard choice? Who provides such a seamless service to deploy Rails apps?

Comment: I don't know that Heroku *is* the "standard choice". It's *a* choice, e.g., https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/rails-host-comparison-aws-digitalocean-heroku-engineyard. I already told you why a lot of people use Heroku. Define "seamless". Puppet/Chef/Vagrant is more like Puppet v. Chef, and Vagrant, e.g., http://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/1yj0y1/how_should_i_choose_between_puppet_chef_and/.

Comment: Thanks again for your time Dave Newton. Seamless? - heroku create - git push heroku master --- ...and your app is online. I say Heroku is the standard choice because is the only one that I have seen exposed in every single lesson about Rails. I went to a bootcamp, Heroku. Michael Hartl tutorial, Heroku. Udemy Rails courses, Heroku. At work, Heroku. Either Heroku is the easiest, or they have a wonderful marketing team.